# Why can I have a ratio object in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I am learning `ratio` in C++11. According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ratio/ratio/) and the book Professional C++ 2nd (the following paragraph is an excerpt from it).

> The numerator and denominator of a rational number are represented as
>   compile time constants of type `std::intmax_t`. Because of the compile
>   time nature of these rational numbers, using them might look a bit
>   complicated and different than usual. You cannot define a ratio object
>   the same way as you define normal objects, and you cannot call methods
>   on it. You need to use `typedefs`.

That means I have to write

```
typedef ratio<1,3> one_third;
```

instead of

```
ratio<1,3> one_third;
```

But I find that these two ways of write ratio are both working. And I can access members of ratio using either `.` or `::`.

**Question 1. Are the cplusplus.com and the Professional C++ book wrong?**

The following snippet is from cplusplus.com example.

```
typedef std::ratio<1,3> one_third;
typedef std::ratio<2,4> two_fourths;
typedef std::ratio_add<one_third,two_fourths> sum;
std::cout << sum::den << std::endl;
```

**Question 2.  However, I got an error (with VS 2012)**

```
error C2039: 'den' : is not a member of 'std::ratio_add<_R1,_R2>'
```

According to the comments, using `typedef ratio_add<one_third, two_fourths>::type sum` is more portable.

Comment: I think you want to use `#define` instead of `typedef`.

Comment: @Havenard I don't see any way in which `#define` would have an advantage here, and the usual drawbacks are sufficiently well-known that I hope I do not need to mention them here. Why do you think `#define` would be better?

Comment: @Havenard I am not why do you prefer `#define` over `typedef` here. `typedef` is used in the code form cplusplus.com and the book. I feel it very strange that I cannot have a ratio object. (which actually works).

Comment: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio_add

Comment: Works for me. http://ideone.com/nJ15Mf

Comment: @champaign: *I feel it very strange that I cannot have a ratio object.* you can't because this ratio management is all compile-time, you don't have object with variables but templates which are resolved at compile time. That's the only thing to know.

Comment: @dyp adding `::type` solves the question 2. Now I see the sample code in cplusplus.com is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @dyp `ratio_add` has `num` and `den`.

Comment: IMHO, looks more complicated than writing a *Fraction* class. *I* would rather work with my own or a library `Fraction` class.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oops, you're right. It's not even a usual metafunction, it just *also* provides the same interface.

Comment: The code is fine, perhaps your standard library implementation isn't. See http://ideone.com/4nKryf

Comment: Out of curiosity, what compiler and version are you using?

Comment: @champaign Are you saying you got the error *after* getting rid of the typedefs? The example I've linked to in my answer compiles and runs correctly on VS2013.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The idea is to calculate everything at compile time. So it does different stuff than a typical fraction class (although `constexpr` could allow you to have a bit of both.)

Comment: @Praetorian I got the error if I do not add `::type` when define `sum`. That is `typedef ratio_add<a,b> sum`. Then access `sum::den` generates the error.

Comment: @champaign It's a VS2012 [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786967/std-ratio-arithmetic-classes-not-working-as-specified) due to that version not supporting alias templates. Fixed in VS2013.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't *have to* use `typedef`s, but as the book says, `<ratio>` deals with compile time math, and the meta-functions defined within it take type template arguments.

If you don't use a `typedef` you're creating an instance of `std::ratio<1,3>` named `one_third`, which is not suitable for passing as a type argument. In that case you'll need to use `decltype` to get to the appropriate type that can be passed to `ratio_add`

```
std::ratio<1,3> one_third;
std::ratio<2,4> two_fourths;
std::ratio_add<decltype(one_third), decltype(two_fourths)> sum;
std::cout << decltype(sum)::den << std::endl;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d47a5f5dc15ed7d8)

---

The error message you're seeing is because the `ratio_add` (and other similar meta-functions') implementation is [not standard conforming on VS2012](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786967/std-ratio-arithmetic-classes-not-working-as-specified) due to lack of support for alias templates. As described in the linked bug report, the workaround is to use the nested type `type`.

```
typedef std::ratio_add<one_third,two_fourths>::type sum;
std::cout << sum::den << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works on ideone.com/. But generating error `error C2039: 'den' : is not a member of '`global namespace'` and `error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'std::ratio_add<_R1,_R2>'` in VS 2012. I think I should **better** just use `<ratio>` as a type not an object in my code.

Comment: @champaign IIRC VS2012 also has a bug that won't let you use `::whatever` after a `decltype` expression. That might be what you're running into.